# Manipulating <body> with jQuery? (Or figuring a better solution)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a JS-script to make modifications to add a footer to HTML -documents on the fly. The idea is to append a div-element at the end of the document to contain the footer, and to provide a floating fixed footer, I also need to have all of the other content wrapped in a div, basically I need something like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Foobar</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="contentWrapper">
    <!-- Content is here -->
  </div>
  <div id="footerWrapper">
    <!-- Footer goes here -->
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The problem is, that the HTML is generated from a system where the end user's have had a little too much control over the structure (it's a blogging platform), and there's no guarantee of a certain sturcture hence I need to wrap the content in a div to ensure the footer works ok.

What I tried, and realized that doesn't work is:

```
$(document.body).wrap($('<div/>').attr('id','footerWrapper'));
```

The problem with this is that due to the fact that the HTML structure is generated by the user, I have been forced to inject links to the JS-file inside the `<body>`-tag. So now when I call wrap(), it seems that everything is first removed from $(document.body) and then appended in the new div. Since the JS-files are linked from inside , calling wrap() seems to remove them momentarily, and it seems that the scripts are unloaded by the browser and everything stops working and I'm left with a blank page. Not exactly what I had in mind.

Next idea was to first copy the JS-tags to the head-element to preserve them, so I wrapped them in a div (yeah, ugly, I know), and tried to copy them to the :

```
$(document.head).append($('#copyToHead').html());
```

That didn't do anything, and seems that $(document.head) isn't usable with functions such as .html() and .append().

So, now I'm out of ideas. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you very sure about that title edit? He was wanting to manipulate the head tag (thus the copyToHead) *or* find a better way (do things successfully from <body>). Unless I've misread.

Comment: @DN: He needs to modify body inline, the way I understand it - trying to edit `<head>` was last resort

Comment: @Adam, we don't disagree. Not a big deal, I guess.

Comment: @DN: so... modifying `<body>` is better, since that is primary objective, not? We may agree to not disagree... wait...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### idea

If leave fact, that `$(document.body)` doesn't exist, wrapping everything into div and then setting id through `attr` might be problematic (don't ask me why—it just happens). So I played with it and created this little snippet (with preview, 100% working).

Since you can't play with html, but can "append" `script` I did whole document manipulation through inline script.

#### code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("body")
      .wrapInner('<div id="wrapper"/>')
      .append('<div id="footer">footer text</div>');
  });
  </script>
```

#### preview

http://jsbin.com/ezoqo4/3

#### edits:

- further simplification and proper markup generation

Comment: Wait, didn't work completely. For some reason it wraps stuff correctly, then the page goes blank, but I think I have some extra code lying around in the page that does funky stuff.

Answer (score 1):

> $(document.head) isn't usable with functions such as .html() and .append().

That would be because document.head is `undefined`

Use `$("head")[0]`

Comment: Seriously. I'd given this up. If that works, I'm going to ..effusively plotz.

Comment: Do you need to do something like var $head = $("head")[0] ? Can jQuery chain off the [0]?

Answer (score 1):

not clear on what your are trying to add to the head part. if you are simply trying to add a div to the end here is a solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $(document.body).append($('<div></div>').attr('id','mydiv').html('This is footer'));
            });
```

Comment: The problem here was wrapping the existing content. To get a footer that sticks to the bottom of the page, I need the structure as explained in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should serve you better:

```
$('body')
    .children ().wrapAll ($('<div/>').attr('id','contentWrapper'))
    .end ()
    .append ($('<div/>').attr('id','footerWrapper'))
;
```

Ref: [`wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)